# What are these little creatures on the fish?

Tags: species-identification

I'm not a fisherman, but I just caught a cod fish (my first one) and found a lot of strange little creatures all over the fish:

[image]

What are those? Are they harmful to the fish, or to the human?

Edit: it's caught on Faroe Islands

Comment: For identification questions please: 1) upload an image, and 2) include the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better). ——— The location can be an essential clue for identification and links are discouraged since 1) if they break they render this post and any answers worthless, and 2) they can be used to link to malicious websites. Thanks! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though it's hard to say exactly what you're talking about based on the image, that cod appears to have several sea lice on it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_louse

Sea lice are common parasites of fish.